# draw to gtk window

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I have a gtk drawing area embedded in a gtk frame, in a gtk window.  I have a callback function responding to "draw" signal that draws something to drawing area initially.  Now I have another function that responds to the "click" signal emitted by a few buttons.  Each time a button is clicked, i would like to draw something additionally to the drawing area.  How can this be accomplished? I have tried making a new cairo surface with the drawing area being the target, but nothing drawn by the cairo stroke is showing up.
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done anything with Gtk+, but I believe what you want to do is call `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()` inside the `"click"` handler, then do the drawing in response to the "`draw`" signal that will eventually be raised.

Comment: thank you.  I was trying to draw inside the click call back function, but queue draw area works just as well

Comment: @jop - I think the thing is that many graphics platforms (X included) can only have drawing happen in response to an event or callback.  So the way to do it is have the click trigger such an event.